# JSON parsing without array name or node in Android

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have a JSOn array without array name and I'm confused how to parse it and how to make JSONObject or JSONArray. If possible then please describe it.

My JSON Array list is:

```
[{
name:"Product_fill",
image:"https://something.com/product1.jpg",
title:"Laptop 1"
},
{
name:"Product_fill2",
image:"https://something.com/product2.jpg",
title:"Laptop 2"
},
```

and my code is :

```
    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String Url="http://msomething.com/list.php";
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //weatherData.setText("Response is :- ");
                parseData(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("Data Not Received");

            }
        });

        queue.add(request);
        super.onStart();


    }

    private void parseData(String response) {
        try {
            // Create JSOn Object
           JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
           JSONObject main=jsonObject.getJSONObject("array");
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("0");

 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
textView.setText(jsonObject1.getString("name"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 try {
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
      for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length() ; i++) {
     JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);  
     textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));   
     }    
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Thnx alot Hemant sir for giving me best solution regarding loop

Comment: @PradeepSheoran welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the response string to the JSONArray constructor directly and then parse the array using a loop

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Tip: I would search how to use other json libraries like Gson or Jackson as the Android built-in parser is not good.

Comment: super its working for me , thanks alot Ahmed sir.

Comment: Sir , This show complete array in a textview so how we collect name, image and title seprately

Comment: The for loop as included in your question exactly

Comment: by this loop its working for me :  for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                      {
                          JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                          textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                     }

Comment: i'm lot of thnxfull

Comment: You can mark this as the accepted answer if it answers your question then :)